# Reactjs useEffect to capture multiples Firebase Firestore onSnapshot events

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to show master/detailed data from Firestore on realtime using React.js.

The "Dashboard" collection has "Cards" collection, that has "Devices" data.

For instance

- My Dashboard

  - Card 1

    - kitchen
    - bedroom
  - Card 2

    - living room
    - balcony

I can [Subscribe To One Firestore Changes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugAgovxfX1U) using React.useEffect

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  return db.collection("dashboards").onShapshot(snap ...)
}, []);
```

When I try to seek for the nested card data, I am facing a lot of problems. Simply I don't know the way to do it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problems you're facing? What error messages? 
Have you read the React useEffect docs about subscribing/unsubscribing listeners inside useHook? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? It's difficult to guess what the issue is without the complete code, so could you share the remainder of your `onSnapshot()` code? Also a better explanation of what nested data you are looking for would be useful, do you mean any subcollections of simply raw data?